# Number of regions formed by circles

Tags: algorithm, math, geometry

I have an array of circles with their center x and y coordinates and the corresponding radius.

Return the count of the regions created by those circles as the response.

**Example:**
I have 3 circles:

```
[x,y,r]
[-2,0,1]
[0,0,2]
[2,0,1]
```

**Ans:**

```
Number of regions formed are 6.
```

**Explanation:**

[image]

5 regions are inside the circles and 1 region is outside of the circles.

**Constraints:**

```
x & y range from -50 to 50
radius range is 1 to 50
```

I'm Java developer, I tried learning about circles but was still unable to come up with an idea to solve this problem.

What is the approach to solving this?

Comment: By "find', you mean "count"?

Comment: @MattTimmermans, yes, I have updated my post

Comment: So a single circle will yield two zones? And no circle will show just one zone?

Comment: @WJS, yes single circle means 2 regions or zones, no circle means 1 region

Comment: According to this webpage: [Regions Made by Intersecting Circles](http://mathelogical.in/non-routine-mathematics/regions-made-by-circles/), the formula is: `n(n - 1) + 2` where `n` would be the number of elements in your _array of circles_.

Comment: Are all circle on the same `y` ? Because if it the case you can check intersection number with the `y axe` to optain the number of regions.

Comment: @Cortard, y need not be same for circles.

Comment: All of the solutions I can think of for this problem are pretty difficult.  Are you sure you don't have any other constraints?

Comment: @MattTimmermans, I have added the constraints to the post now, please check

Comment: @technotigr is it possible for three or more circles to intersect in the same point?

Comment: @Luatic, yes intersection is also possible

Comment: @technotigr So *three or more circles* intersecting *in the same point* is something that occurs? That would greatly complicate an exact answer (note that three or more circles intersecting is fine for my "simple" approach so long as they don't *intersect all in the same point).

Answer (score 1):

As noted in a comment by user85421, we can use Euler's formula:

v - e + f = 2

where v is the number of vertices (intersection points), e is the number of edges (arcs between intersection points) and and f is the number of faces (areas) to solve for. We obtain f = 2 + e - v. Each intersection point adds twice as many edges as vertices, so we have e = 2v and thus f = 2 + 2v - v = 2 + v.

For simplicity, I will make the strong assumption that no three or more circles intersect in the same point. This means that each intersection point between two circles is a node/vertex. If you can't make this assumption, you would have to deduplicate shared intersection points using something like a hash set of intersections points. However intersection points need not have rational coordinates, so this can be problematic due to rounding error; you can either discretize down to some epsilon of precision, or you could try to work out an exact representation (assuming rational circle coordinates) of intersection points, which is tricky if possible at all.

Under this assumption, you can just check each circle for intersections with all other circles in O(n²) time (if you want to speed this up, look into spatial indexing data structures such as k-d-trees, or perhaps [M-trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M-tree) here), counting each intersection as a vertex. Note that this will count all vertices twice (once for both involved circles).

We also need to be careful in our case analysis of the intersection of two circles:

- Two circles could be equal, "intersecting" in infinitely many points. We assume this is not the case in the input.
- One circle could be inside the other circle; they may be touching in a single point then, or they may not touch at all.
- Otherwise, they may intersect in one point, two points, or not at all.

In my code, I have used two exact comparisons for circles touching in a single point. This is a problem with floats/doubles in principle, *but* integer arithmetic on doubles is exact, so this will work correctly for some integer-only cases. Note however that since the code does not use `sqrt`, you could make it use rational numbers implemented on top of Java's `BigInteger` (that is out of scope for this answer, though) to do exact computations.

Code:

```java
record Circle(double x, double y, double r) {
    int intersections(Circle other) {
        // If the circles were equal, we would have infinitely many intersections
        assert !equals(other);
        // No need to sqrt (precision and possibly performance concern),
        // just square the radii as well and compare with the squared distance.
        var dx = x - other.x;
        var dy = y - other.y;
        var dSq = dx*dx + dy*dy;
        // Deal with one circle being inside the other
        var dr = Math.abs(r - other.r);
        var drSq = dr*dr;
        if (dSq < drSq) return 0;
        if (dSq == drSq) return 1;
        // Circle isn't inside the other one,
        // compare against total radius
        var tr = r + other.r;
        var trSq = tr*tr;
        if (dSq > trSq) return 0;
        if (dSq == trSq) return 1;
        return 2;
    }
    static int regions(Circle[] circles) {
        int intersections = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
            int iIntersections = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < circles.length; j++) {
                // Don't count intersections of circle with itself
                if (i == j) continue;
                int ijIntersections = circles[i].intersections(circles[j]);
                // This makes the strong assumption that no more than two circles intersect in the same point.
                iIntersections += ijIntersections;
            }
            // In a planar graph, a lone circle is modeled as a single node connected to itself;
            // HACK treat that as two intersections, which has the same effect of adding one region.
            intersections += (iIntersections == 0) ? 2 : iIntersections;
        }
        // Account for the fact that we counted intersections twice.
        assert intersections % 2 == 0;
        return 2 + intersections / 2;
    }
}
```

This handles at least your example correctly:

```java
System.out.println(Circle.regions(new Circle[] {
    new Circle(-2, 0, 1),
    new Circle(0, 0, 2),
    new Circle(2, 0, 1),
})); // 6
```